# select join in the same table

Tags: join, plsql

I have a table like this

[image]

TRX_NUMBER is a invoice, and this field have a return number inside of the invoice.

And I want to select table and join to the same table use CUSTOMER_TRX_ID and PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID as the connection (ON)

And the result what I want

[image]

Can you help me about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with invoice (customer_trx_id, trx_number, previous_customer_trx_id) as
  2    (select 81196, 'ARR05-09', 22089 from dual union all
  3     select 22089, 'IJU86-09', null  from dual union all
  4     select 13931, 'IJU07-09', null  from dual
  5    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  6  select a.trx_number, b.trx_number as retur
  7  from invoice a left join invoice b on a.customer_trx_id = b.previous_customer_trx_id
  8  where not exists (select null
  9                    from invoice c
 10                    where c.customer_trx_id = a.previous_customer_trx_id);

TRX_NUMBER      RETUR
--------------- --------
IJU86-09        ARR05-09
IJU07-09

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias to take the same table multiple times.

For example we have a table INVOICE:

```
SELECT t1.TRX_NUMBER AS TRX_NUMBER, t2.TRX_NUMBER AS RETUR
FROM INVOICE t1
LEFT JOIN INVOICE t2 ON t1.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = t2.PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
```

if only one level then add a condition

```
where not exists (select null
                    from invoice t3
                    where t3.customer_trx_id = t1.previous_customer_trx_id)
```

or exclude everything where there is a previous number - it means they are already a level lower

```
where t1.PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER_TRX_ID is null
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because **a)** it is invalid (in Oracle, table alias doesn't allow the AS keyword), **b)** it is invalid some more (missing the ON keyword in JOIN), **c)** when fixed, doesn't return desired result.

Comment: @Littlefoot ty; a) I use "AS" to designate an alias (t1,t2). b) yep, fix it. c) add "LEFT" should work now.

Comment: Now it works, but still produces wrong result.

Comment: @Littlefoot fixed it for conditions where there is only one level of nesting.

Comment: Right; and now, now you've got exact copy of code I already posted :)

Comment: @Littlefoot part of it but offered more options :)